# Get variables become inaccessible after htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, rewrite

I'm trying to work with SEO friendly urls and as a result am using htaccess to redirect to a more friendly destination. However, when I do these redirects, I am no longer able to access the get variables from the new url, even though I can get them when I go to the old one. I'm specifically looking at the "writer" line although I've included the rest for context. Any idea on how I can fix this issue?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^writer/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+) writer?user=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+) article?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like MultiViews might be enabled. Since you have `writer` in the URL and `writer.php` (same basename) as the file being rewritten to, you need to ensure that MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation) is disabled, otherwise MultiViews will issue an internal subrequest for `writer.php` (without URL parameters) *before* your mod_rewrite directives are able to process the request.

At the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

> ```
> RewriteRule ^writer/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+) writer?user=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

You should also be rewriting directly to the file that's handling the request. With the above directive, you are reliant on another directive further rewriting the request (during a second pass) to append the necessary file extension.

In other words:

```
RewriteRule ^writer/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+) writer.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
> ```

And change the order of the directives, so the "catch-all" rule to append the file extension is last. However, you can't rewrite to an absolute filesystem path in `.htaccess`, this needs to be a URL-path, so use `REQUEST_URI` instead of `REQUEST_FILENAME` in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
```

However, depending on your filesystem structure, `REQUEST_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_URI` won't necessarily refer to the same URL-path. So, it may be safer to use `REQUEST_URI` in the *condition* as well. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
```

You also might want to exclude requests that contain any file extension, such as your static resources (images, css, js). As it stands, there will be a (relatively expensive) filesystem for each of these requests as well.

### In Summary:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^writer/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+) writer.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+) article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> .htaccess is found in public_html while writer.php is found in a folder under public_html called users

If `writer.php` is located in the `/users` subdirectory then you'll obviously need to refer to this subdirectory somewhere, either in the directive (*susbstitution* string) itself, or perhaps using a `RewriteBase` directive if all files being rewritten to are in this subdirectory.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^writer/([0-9a-zA-z_-]+) users/writer.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Since the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root, then the above directive assumes you are making a request of the form `/writer/abc`. If the request is actually for `/users/writer/abc` then you will need to modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* accordingly (or move the `.htaccess` file into the `/users` subdirectory - but then you shouldn't modify the *substitution* string).

Note that a *substitution* string (ie. `users/writer.php?user=$1`) without a leading slash (or scheme + hostname) is seen as *relative*. It is relative to the location of the `.htaccess` file, unless a `RewriteBase` is defined that states otherwise.

(Since `writer.php` was seemingly getting called originally, without any URL parameters, then that sounds like you were perhaps making a request of the form `/users/writer/abc`?)

Comment: I appreciate the thoroughness of this response but it didn't quite work for me. Maybe the fact that writer.php is under a folder named users will change things? Since it's not directly in the root

Comment: Where is this .htaccess file located? And what is the URL you are requesting?

Comment: .htaccess is found in public_html while writer.php is found in a folder under public_html called users

Comment: ...And what is the URL being requested? If the file being rewritten to is in a subdirectory, then you'll need to refer to that subdirectory somewhere. I've updated my answer. Presumably you don't have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file or any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: How did you get on with this?